# Read arraylist of map from file in kotlin

Tags: input, kotlin

I have saved the following data in a file from console:

```
Username : ali 
Age : 56 
Email : abc@gmail.com
Password :123456
Skills :Skills : [{android=2, java=3}, {android=2, java=3}]
```

The last field is an arrayList of maps.

```
var skills = arrayListOf<Map<String, Int>>()
var skill = mutableMapOf<String,Int>()
var skillType: String

print("Skills with experience : ")
   skillType = readLine()!!
   print("Experience : ")
   skill[skillType] = readLine()!!.toInt()

   skills.add(skill)
```

Now I want to read this skills field as the same arrayList of maps to check some particular skill is present or not. How can I do this?

Comment: toString() is not mean to provide an unambiguous, parseable representation of an object. Don't use that to store data in a file. Choose a parseable format, like JSON or XML.

Comment: As i am learning, working on console

Comment: So what? I'm not advising you to create a webapp or a GUI or anything. I'm advising you to choose a parseable format for the data you're storing in a file if you want to be able to parse that data. The fact that you're "working on console" doesn't prevent you from doing that.

Comment: Ok.Do you give me any link for that?

Comment: Google for "how to parse JSON in Java".

Answer (score 1):

options for serializing kotlin to json are using

- Jackson (it has a kotlin module)
  https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin
- (my own recommendation) JetBrain's own kotlinx-serialization but it requires a gradle setup
  the gradle-plugin generates the serializers for you so it manages to be reflectionless and supports kotlin-native too
  https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization
- there are some more kotlin implementations for json serialization (eg: klaxon)
- and even more in just java (eg: gson)

hope that gives you somewhere to start and compare your options

and for kotlinx-serialization some same code

```
@Serializable
data class Skill(val skillType: SkillType)

enum class SkillType { A, B, C }

val json = JSON(indented = true)

println(json.stringify(Skill::class.serializer().list, listOf(Skill(SKillType.A))))

println(json.stringify(Skill(SkillType.B)))

val skill: Skill = json.parse("{\"skillType\": \"C\"}")
```

some other notes, it allows to have json "unquoted" , so remove quotes where it is possible, makes it a lot more readable
and human consumable